# How can I inject large HTML file into iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I need to inject HTML into an iFrame dynamically. How can I "wrap" this html so that it will be properly escaped so I can pass it as a js var?

Here is what I have. So far it looks as if the first line of the html is stored in 'content' but then the rest is displayed in the browser window (outside the frame).

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     var content = <%=Model.Html%>;
    var doc = document.getElementById("testFrame");
    if (iframe.contentDocument)
        doc = iframe.contentDocument; // For NS6
    else if (iframe.contentWindow)
        doc = iframe.contentWindow.document; // For IE5.5 and IE6
    // Put the content in the iframe
    doc.open();
    doc.writeln(content);
    doc.close();
</script>
```

I have an iFrame on the page with

> id = "testFrame"
>
> <%=Model.Html%> Contains the HTML that I am trying to inject. Its includes some JS inline. This document is what I need to "wrap".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a ASP.NET MVC application I just created a new action (GetHtml) that returns Html.

I set the src of the iFrame to this new action. Like so:

```
<iframe id="testFrame" name="testFrame" src ="<%= Url.Action("GetHtml","MyController", new{href = Model.Href}) %>>" width="100%" height="600">
    <p>
        Your browser does not support iframes.
    </p>
</iframe>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetHtml()
{
...
return Content(htmlContent, "text/html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using .src attribute of your iframe?

```
var doc = document.getElementById("testFrame");
doc.src = <%=Model.html%>;
```

Or you also could refresh it with AJAX and use `doc.src=req.responseText;`

Comment: Same problem.. thanks for the suggestion. I need the HTML to be escaped somehow it would appear.